# BIGQUERY/ Json is not enabled for current project

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I am working on Bigquery. The data is from firestore.
But the schema data is all of type string. And I want to pass them to JSON.
I want to use PARSE_JSON or TO JSON to convert a string to JSON. But I get an error:
***Json is not enabled for the current project.***
***Json is not enabled for current project.***

Answer (score 3):

JSON datatype is currently in preview.  See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data for more information, including enrollment.